# Executing a shell script on a remote host through ssh which inturn runs ssh to another host to apply database changes

Tags: ssh

I am trying to run a shell script on a remote host (A) through ssh. The shell script inturn uses SSH to connect to another host (B) to perform some database related operations. However it looks the agent is not being forwarded when connecting to Host B and I see a connection refused.

This is equivalent to executing ssh command as follows

ssh -A some@A.com "ssh some@B.com 'ls'"

I have used -A to enable agent forwarding but still no luck.

Please let me know how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: I even tried this `ssh -A some@A.com "ssh -A some@B.com 'ls'"` but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

So silly of me. Firewall issue rather than ssh issue. Host A had no permission to connect to Host B. Should have thought this through! Thanks.